# how to check return value of shell cmd in autotools configure

Tags: gnu, autoconf, m4

I would like to run a shell command during the configure process- if the return value of this operation is 0, I would like to use it. Otherwise, I want to exit with error message.

I wrote something like this:

```
LOC=$(perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e perl_inc | sed 's/[ \t]*-I//')
RC=$?
AS_IF([ test $RC != 0 ], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Can't find module MExtUtils::Embed in perl. Try installing perl 5.8.8 or above])],)
```

This won't work. RC always get the value 0, even when the command fails.

Does anyone knows how to do it right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your pipe always succeeds, because `sed` will succeed regardless of what perl does.  One approach would be to simply delay the invocation of `sed`:

```
LOC=$( perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e perl_inc )
AS_IF([ test $? != 0 ], [AC_MSG_ERROR([...])])
LOC=$( echo "$LOC" | sed 's/[ \t]*-I//' )
```

On the other hand, it looks like `perl_inc` is commands to perl rather than the name of a file, so it might be easier to simply add the substitution from sed into your perl.

On the third hand, you should probably just use  [`AX_PROG_PERL_MODULES`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_perl_modules.html) to see if the desired module is installed.